# Finding 'input' tags using XPath in Common Lisp

Tags: xpath, common-lisp

I am trying to scrape an HTML page for a particular input field (so that I can extract a token from it for use during login).  I'm using SBCL 1.0.54 (because that version works properly with StumpWM), quicklisp, and the following quicklisp packages:

```
drakma
closure-html
cxml-stp
```

If I load the HTML page using Drakma, and convert it to valid X(HTML), I can use the following code (loosely adapted frome the Plexippus XPath examples):

```
(xpath:do-node-set (node (xpath:evaluate "//*" xhtml-tree))
  (format t "found element: ~A~%"
    (xpath-protocol:local-name node)))
```

... to obtain the following results (snipped for brevity; the page in question is *large*):

```
found element: img
found element: a
found element: img
found element: script
found element: div
found element: img
found element: a
found element: input
found element: input
```

However I can't seem to get any XPath statement more complicated than "//*" working correctly.  My aim is to find an input with a particular name, but even just finding all inputs fails:

```
* (xpath:evaluate "//input" xhtml-tree)

#<XPATH:NODE-SET empty {10087146F3}>
```

I'm obviously missing something pretty basic here.  Could someone please give me pointer in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be a namespace issue? That is, if there is an `xmlns` attribute on the root `html` element, then you will need to declare the namespace with `xpath:with-namespaces` and specify it in your XPath expression. The expression `"//input"` only finds `input` elements that aren't in any namespace.

Comment: It was indeed a namespace issue, thank you :-)  Using xpath-with-namespaces caused the expression to behave the way I expected.